# VLOOKUP Compare two sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have two sheets currently

```
#Sheet1
1
2
3
4
5

#Sheet2
1,2
2,10
3,5
7,10
5,10
8,20
9,15
```

I have tired matching the first two columns of both the sheets.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A7,1,FALSE).
```

Now I need to get the values from the `Sheet2` `2nd column` for the matched 1st columns of Sheet1 & Sheet2.

```
Expected Result

1,1,2
2,2,10
3,3,5
4,N/A,N/A
5,5,10
```

Comment: I think you want `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B7,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) takes arguments like these:

```
=Vlookup([lookup value],[lookup range],[column in lookup range],[1/0])
```

For you, you need to include the entire table of values as the lookup range and return the 2nd column's value

```
=Vlookup(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$7,2,0)
```